# In C# How Do You Get Variables From Another Class

Tags: c#, class, variables, get

I have an API with several classes. Within one class I want to use the variables from the other classes. How do I go about doing this?

Thanks!

```
public class Rain
{
    public decimal rainValueInCM;
    public decimal rainValueInMM;
   // public Dictionary<decimal, Temperature> Temperature = new Dictionary<decimal, Temperature>();

    public Rain(decimal cm)
    {
        rainValueInCM = cm;
    }

    public  decimal ConvertToCM(decimal mm)
    {   
        rainValueInCM = (mm / 10);
        return rainValueInCM;  
    }
```

For instance, in another class, I want to use the variable 'rainValueInCM' from this class.

Comment: There are many ways to do what you are requesting, and depends on what are you triying to achieve... Post some code and we will help you

Comment: `sniker` Carefully! http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/578116/Complete-Managed-Media-Aggregation-Part-III-Quantu

Answer (score 2):

Simply you have to create an instance of the class `Rain` and access it values this way:

```
public class Rain
{
    public decimal rainValueInCM;
    public decimal rainValueInMM;
   // public Dictionary<decimal, Temperature> Temperature = new Dictionary<decimal, Temperature>();

    public Rain(decimal cm)
    {
        rainValueInCM = cm;
    }

    public  decimal ConvertToCM(decimal mm)
    {   
        rainValueInCM = (mm / 10);
        return rainValueInCM;  
    }
}

public class AnotherClass
{
     public void SomeMethod() 
     {
         Rain myRain = new Rain(5); // create the instance
         // use the value
         decimal theValue = myRain.rainValueInCM;
     }
}
```

Anyway I recommend you to read about [C# properties](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x9fsa0sw.aspx), since there isn't a good practice to expose as public your class value members. Gook luck!

Answer (score 0):

First you need a `getter` and `setter` for the `property`

```
public class Rain
{
    public decimal rainValueInCM { get; set; }
    ...
}
```

Then instantiate an `object` of `type` `Rain` in the other `class` and get the `property`

```
public class MyOtherClass
{
    public void MyMethod() {
         Rain rain = new Rain();
         decimal cm = rain.rainValueInCM;
    }

}
```

Comment: Just a minor niggle I have. Property names should ideally be in pascal case.

Naming conventions are important.

Comment: @colonel_px then tell the OP this. While I understand what you're saying, it's not required.